# matplotlib arrow's connectionstyle and width, headwidth are not compatible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
start = (0.1, 0.1)
end = (0.5, 0.5)
connectionstyle='angle,angleA=-90,angleB=10,rad=5'
ax.annotate("",
            xy=end, xycoords='data',
            xytext=start, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            color="0.5",
                            shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                            patchA=None,
                            patchB=None,
                            connectionstyle=connectionstyle,
                            ),)
```

Which can generate a figure like this,

[image]

However, if I use parameters like `width`, `headwidth` instead of `arrowstyle`, I always get a error. Same set of code which has a error report:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
start = (0.1, 0.1)
end = (0.5, 0.5)
connectionstyle='angle,angleA=-90,angleB=10,rad=5'
ax.annotate("",
            xy=end, xycoords='data',
            xytext=start, textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(#arrowstyle="->",
                            width=10,headwidth=30,
                            color="0.5",
                            shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                            patchA=None,
                            patchB=None,
                            connectionstyle=connectionstyle,
                            ),)
```

If I change `connectionstyle` to 'arc3, rad=1', it works fine.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
start = (0.1, 0.1)
end = (0.5, 0.5)
connectionstyle='arc3, rad=1'  # connectionstyle NOW arc3
ax.annotate("",
        xy=end, xycoords='data',
        xytext=start, textcoords='data',
        arrowprops=dict(#arrowstyle="->",
                        width=10,headwidth=30,
                        color="0.5",
                        shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                        patchA=None,
                        patchB=None,
                        connectionstyle=connectionstyle,
                        ),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're still providing `connectionstyle='angle,angleA=-90,angleB=10,rad=5'`, which can not be applied to an annotation *without* `arrowstyle`.

Have a look [at the documentation for annotate](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate), especially at **arrowprops**, where it says:

> If arrowprops **does not contain the key 'arrowstyle'** the allowed keys are:
>   width, headwidth, headlength, shrink, and any key to matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch

Comment: If I want the functionality of connectionstyle as well as adjustable arrow what should I do? It seems it is not that flexible...

Comment: @ted930511 then you should use valid arguments inside the `arrowprops` dict, e.g. `mutation_scale=30, linewidth=5`, see the [documentation for FancyArrowPatch](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch)

Comment: Is it really the problem of `connectionstyle`, please see my updated example, when I change connectionstyle to 'arc3' without `arrowstyle`, it can work. So your statement `which can not be applied to an annotation without arrowstyle` seems not completely true. `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` also have an argument `connectionstyle`.